# Sending email via Outlook using Python, contact group doesn't resolve

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

The recipient address and the distro lists do not immediately resolve. Outlook is smart enough to recognize the email addresses, but it doesn't recognize my distro list. At least not immediately.

I'm using Office 365 if that matters.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch


outlook = Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
Mail_Item = outlook.CreateItem(0)

# This sends no problem
# Mail_Item.To = 'first.last@company.com'

# This does not send
Mail_Item.To = 'Contact_Group_Test'

Mail_Item.Subject = "Subject_text"
Mail_Item.Body = "Body_text"
Mail_Item.Recipients.ResolveAll()
Mail_Item.Send()
```

While troubleshooting I used `Mail_Item.Display()` to see the message. After a few seconds it resolves all my addresses, including the contact group. HOWEVER, the contact group itself still doesn't work despite this.

Answer (score 1):

If you couldn't solve, you can try smtplib.

```
import smtplib

sender = 'from@fromdomain.com'
receivers = ['to@todomain.com']

message = """From: From Person <from@fromdomain.com>
To: To Person <to@todomain.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
"""

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
   print "Successfully sent email"
except SMTPException:
   print "Error: unable to send email"
```

If you will send mail from outlook account, you have to write `smtp-mail.outlook.com` instead of `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

mtbenj's answer may work for others. I'm just choosing to go the win32com route because of my organization.

For whatever reason using 'Test', and I'm assuming, any one-word contact list takes ~5 seconds to resolve. I counted after the `.Display()` popup came up. Naming it 'Test_' didn't do it for me either.

I decided to try one named 'Test_Test'. After calling `.Recipients.ResolveAll()`, it works perfect.

So use an underscore and multiple words.